# What is the best way to call a function with the result of a filter operation on a Java stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm wondering what the best way is to read a file using the new Java 8 stream API, filter the input stream by a pattern match, and then pass the result to a function that consumes the groups from the match.  I expect that's not possible, because stream operations are stateless and the groups from the pattern matcher cannot be passed to the next step in the stream processor.

So, let's say I have this

> stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())

Is it possible to add a callout to a function that takes s or, preferably, the groups from the matches()?  Something like

> stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches()).ifTrue(s -> myfunc(s))

I basically want to avoid collecting all my matches to an in-memory data structure, because I don't know how big my stream is.  Let's say I have a huge file and I want to construct and serialize an object that encapsulates the pattern matcher's groups.  I don't want to hold all the matches in a single data structure and process that imperatively, so what is the best way to operate on the file such that I can process a single line and limit my memory consumption while also allowing for the file to be processed in parallel?

Is it better to just iterate over the lines and process those one-at-a-time?  Would this be equivalent to the terminal operation of forEach() on the stream?  In my use case, I probably don't care about the side-effects of not being able to parallelize on the terminal operation, but I am curious about the general case when forEach would be problematic during parallel processing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is a bit weird. If you call `matches` it implies that your entire `String` matches, so the element *is* the match.

And it makes no sense to ask for a `.ifTrue(s -> myfunc(s))` method on a stream, actually, it makes me wonder what you think `filter` does. If you chain an action after `filter`, it will applied to the matches only as that’s the purpose of `filter`.

So `stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches()).forEach(s -> myfunc(s))` is the right tool for the job and it implies neither, collection of data nor multi-threading issues. If your function `myfunc` has no threading issues on its own, `filter(…).forEach(…)` can run in parallel without problems.

---

Its worth noting that `Pattern` has an [`asPredicate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate--) method. It uses `find` rather than `matches`, but this can be fixed by adding the anchor to the pattern:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "ab", "bb", "aaa", "bab")
      .filter(Pattern.compile("^a*$").asPredicate())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print

```
a
aaa
```

and will work with `parallel` as well (only the order might change).

---

If you really need the state of the `Matcher`, you have to options.

1. Create the `Matcher` first and apply `filter` afterwards:

   ```
   Pattern p=Pattern.compile("b(a+)b");
   Stream.of("a", "b", "bab", "bb", "aa", "baaab")//.parallel()
         .map(p::matcher)
         .filter(Matcher::matches)
         .mapToInt(m->m.end(1)-m.start(1))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Use `flatMap` and express the combined result of mapping and filtering with a result `Stream`

   ```
   Pattern p=Pattern.compile("b(a+)b");
   Stream.of("a", "b", "bab", "bb", "aa", "baaab")//.parallel()
         .flatMap(s-> { Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
             return m.matches()? Stream.of(m.group(1)): Stream.empty(); })
         .mapToInt(String::length)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

Both will print `1` and `3` and are safe for `parallel` execution; using `forEach` with a parallel stream might change the order, that’s all. You may use [`forEachOrdered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) if you are interested in the source order.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to this one, because I feel it more accurately discusses the behaviour of streams with respect to the question at hand.  In fact, I did go with forEach() as opposed to peek(), because I needed a terminal operation to force the file to be processed.

Comment: Separate comment to discuss why streams don't work for my use case.  What I was looking for was a way to process an infinite file stream, which isn't possible using the Stream API.  I ended up going with the commons-io Tailer library, because it gives me the behaviour I want, which is to process each line and execute a handler to process it.  Meanwhile, I want to keep the pipe open to process new lines as they are written to the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can [`peek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) at the stream.

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

The stream is intact, but you can perform your operation with a lambda expression (a `Consumer`).

```
stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches()).peek(s -> myfunc(s))
```